# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file, but it's in the same directory

Tags: c

I am trying to compile some C code (generated from python using cpython), and I'm getting the C1083 error saying the file doesn't exist.

`structmember.h` is actually in the same folder as the C file, and is also in its `include` folder in case it was looking there instead, so I've no idea how to fix it. I'm attempting to generate the file by using `cl test.c`.

Here's the entire output:

```
C:\test>cl test.c
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.10.25019 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

test.c
test.c(1018): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'structmember.h': No such file or directory
```

Here's a shot from the folder:
[image]

Here is the code around each mention of structmember (took screenshots as coping a full page of text probably isn't useful):

### [image]

[image]

If anyone would like to have a glance at the file, it's on onedrive [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ai6sg-RxOdJhn2bncffVqs9FE25c), a little too large for pastebin.

Comment: How do you include this file?

Comment: It's generated code with Cython and about 50k lines, I'll edit the post the code around each include

Comment: Added some shots of where it's included

Comment: Why is your file to include in angle brackets <>? Include it in quotes.

Comment: I personally aren't aware of the C syntax and was relying on the generated code, but thanks, that appeared to work. The script itself appears to be horribly broken by the conversion, but at least it complies, cheers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft compilers will not look in the cpp folder when using the #include <> form.

Change your include statement to the correct form for including a 'local' header.

```
#include "structmember.h"
```

Comment: Yeah cheers, I don't suppose you'd know why it happened to use <> instead of quotes? Seems a weird bug when it's something so simple

Comment: It happens quite often...  Most other compilers do implicitly include the local folder in the include path...  This is afaik a peculiarity of Microsoft.